# Node.js Data-Completion script

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Following task:**

Customer-data, given in a JSON-file, have to be completed with additional address-data. Given in a second JSON-file.

Then these data-stock has to be saved into a MongoDB-database.

**Schema of the customer-JSON:**

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "first_name": "Ario",
      "last_name": "Noteyoung",
      "email": "anoteyoung0@nhs.uk",
      "gender": "Male",
      "ip_address": "99.5.160.227",
      "ssn": "509-86-9654",
      "credit_card": "5602256742685208",
      "bitcoin": "179BsXQkUuC6NKYNsQkdmKQKbMBPmJtEHB",
      "street_address": "0227 Kropf Court"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "first_name": "Minni",
      "last_name": "Endon",
      "email": "mendon1@netvibes.com",
      "gender": "Female",
      "ip_address": "213.62.229.103",
      "ssn": "765-11-9543",
      "credit_card": "67613037902735554",
      "bitcoin": "135wbMcR98R6hqqWgEJXHZHcanQKGRPwE1",
      "street_address": "90 Sutteridge Way"
    },
... 
]
```

**Schema of the addresses-JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "city": "New Orleans",
    "state": "Louisiana",
    "phone": "504-981-8641"
  },
  {
    "country": "United States",
    "city": "New York City",
    "state": "New York",
    "phone": "212-312-1945"
  },
...
]
```

**Desired result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3f16f5743a6704739bf436"),
    "id" : "1",
    "first_name" : "Ario",
    "last_name" : "Noteyoung",
    "email" : "anoteyoung0@nhs.uk",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "ip_address" : "99.5.160.227",
    "ssn" : "509-86-9654",
    "credit_card" : "5602256742685208",
    "bitcoin" : "179BsXQkUuC6NKYNsQkdmKQKbMBPmJtEHB",
    "street_address" : "0227 Kropf Court",
    "country" : "United States",
    "city" : "New Orleans",
    "state" : "Louisiana",
    "phone" : "504-981-8641"
  },
  ...
]
```

**My solution:**

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const filePathCustomer = "./customers.json";
const filePathAddresses = "./addresses.json";

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

completeCustomers = (filePathCustomers, filePathAddresses) => {
  const customers = require(filePathCustomers);
  const addresses = require(filePathAddresses);

  return (updatedCustomers = customers.map((customer, index) => {
    const updatedCustomer = Object.assign(customer, addresses[index]);

    return updatedCustomer;
  }));
};

MongoClient.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/bitcoinExchange",
  (error, client) => {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error("Connecting to MongoDb has failed.");
    }

    const db = client.db();

    let execCompleteCustomer = new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(completeCustomers(filePathCustomer, filePathAddresses));
    });

    execCompleteCustomer
      .then(customer => {
        db.collection("customers").insertMany(customer, (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            db.close();
            throw new Error("Writing to database has failed");
          }
          console.log(
            "Count of customer documents inserted:",
            result.insertedCount
          );

          return true;
        });
      })
      .then(result => {
        if (result) db.close();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        db.close();
        throw new Error("The merging of the customer-data has failed.");
      });
  }
);
```

**What would you have done different and why?**

**Is my error-handling done in a good way and fashion? How could it be improved?**

What bothers me a bit are this multiple occurences of db.close().

**Is there a way in Node to avoid these redundancy?**

Something like finally in Java.

Comment: How do you know which address to couple with which customer? They don't share an identifier and relying on the order in a JSON smells like a bad idea.

Comment: It's exactly the same amount of objects in addresses then in customer. The element n in customer maps to the element n in addresses. E.g.: customer[3] maps to addresses[3] and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just a few things

1. To start out, the return statement in your function `completeCustomers` should/could be changed.

The way the function is defined should also be changed. But we'll get to that in a second.

```
return (updatedCustomers = customers.map((customer, index) => {
  const updatedCustomer = Object.assign(customer, addresses[index]);

  return updatedCustomer;
}));
```

I would replace with:

```
return (updatedCustomers = customers.map((customer, index) => ({
  ...customer,
  ...addresses[index]
})))
```

Note, you don't have to make it take up multiple lines if you don't want.

2. Use const when you don't modify a variable, or arrow function

This means that the two functions below need to change:

```
completeCustomers = (filePathCustomers, filePathAddresses) => {
```

Would become:

```
const completeCustomers = (filePathCustomers, filePathAddresses) => {
```

---

```
let execCompleteCustomer = new Promise(resolve => {
```

And this would become:

```
const execCompleteCustomer = new Promise(resolve => {
```

That's all I have for now, but I'm not getting what part you are saying is redundant. And I think you handled the errors well.